# How to model a database with many users and a lot of rows for each user

Tags: sql, node.js, database, nosql

I have an application in development which works with the last.fm API to retrieve a lot of information for a given last.fm user. For the moment I'm using MYSQL and working with a single user for the time being. I have 12 fields in the table. When I retrieve the data from the last.fm API I get around 30K rows saving in my database and that's just for 1 user.

[image: current Database model]

I want to make this application usable for multiple users.

I don't know how to model my database. I don't have any experience with NoSQL. So just exploring different ways I can save multiple users with a lot of data for each user.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to the correct solution.

Add a `UserID` column to your table. Then you can identify each row of the table as belonging to a particular user.

Comment: Yes I thought of creating a relational model of tables but the problem is the sheer amount of data. Say I have 100 users, on average 30k rows for each user, that's 3 million rows right there.